# Animate a gif file only once

Tags: codenameone

I have a `gif` file added in `cn1` through add animation. But what I need is for it to run only once, then stick in the bottom of the screen. Now it is looping  continuously all the time.

code:

```
@Override
protected void beforeAnimation(Form f) {
    leaf = (Image) r.getImage("leafFinal.gif");
    leafLabel = new Label(leaf);
    f.add(FlowLayout.encloseIn(leafLabel));
    leafLabel.setVisible(false);
}

@Override
protected void postAnimation(Form f) {
    leafLabel.setVisible(true);
    leafLabel.getParent().animateLayoutAndWait(2500);
}
```

[image: The gif I need to play only once.]

How can I get the gif to not run continuosly?

Update: Using scaleImageLabel instead of Label

```
    ScaleImageLabel leafGifImageLabel = new ScaleImageLabel();
    f.add(FlowLayout.encloseIn(leafGifImageLabel));
    leafGifImageLabel.setVisible(true);

    Image leafGif = (Image) r.getImage("800_ng.gif");
    Timeline tLeaf = (Timeline) leafGif;
    tLeaf.setLoop(false);
    leafGifImageLabel.setIcon(tLeaf);
    leafGifImageLabel.getParent().revalidate();
```

It works if i use scaledImageLabel instead of Label but it cancels out transition of other components. And the gif runs very very very slow in devices.

Comment: This is very, very easy to Google - always remember to search first. It seems like this needs to be set in the GIF when it is created

Comment: @Pekka웃 yeah i did that. But when i test the app in mobile device it loops continuosly. If i test that in browser it works but not in app. PS i am using codenameone.

Comment: That's very different, then! I'd edit the question to make that much clearer, show some code, etc.

Comment: There's not much of the code. I add gif image from theme and call it. Thanks anyway. Though i have updated the code in the above question.

Comment: It's not crystal clear in the question that this is something that only happens on mobile devices. Right now, it looks like you were too lazy to Google, and people downvote.

Comment: Since i tag codenameone(its for mobile app basically) in the question, i thought only those who knows cn1 will give solutions. Anyway my mistake... thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Downcast the image to timeline and use `setLoop(false)` as such:

```
Timeline tLeaf = (Timeline) r.getImage("leafFinal.gif");
tLeaf.setLoop(false);
leaf = tLeaf;
```

Notice that this might start before the transition completed so write this code as:

```
f.addShowListener(e -> {
    Timeline tLeaf = (Timeline) r.getImage("leafFinal.gif");
    tLeaf.setLoop(false);
    myLabel.setIcon(tLeaf);
    myLabel.getParent().revalidate();
});
```

Comment: I setLoop to false but the gif doesnt work. It abruptly appears in the bottom. Is it possible gif loops for once. As in the img abov, leaf should fall from top to bottom only once. Thankyou.

Comment: Try adding it to the form and revalidating after the form transition finished showing using addShowListener on the form.

Comment: I am afraid i didn't get you. Can you please update in the answer thankyou.

Comment: hello shai, i have a small problem relating to the size of the gif. I add animation (gif) with size 480* 760, now how can i adjust its size according to the device height. It should start from the upper end to lower end. In tabs, the gif stops in the middle and in smaller devices, it goes beyond. I tried to setPreferredHeight of gif label to display height (not working). I scaled the gif image to screenHeight, the animation too slow & doesnt work. How can i set the timeline image to device width and height?

Comment: It should work with scaling (e.g. ScaledImageLabel) but that might include a performance overhead.

Comment: It works if i use scaledImageLabel instead of Label but it cancels out transition of other components. And the gif runs very very very slow in devices. I updated the code i did above. Moreover it works without using showListener in simulator and doesnt work with showListener.

Comment: The slowness on the devices is probably not something we can do much about for this specific feature. The ScaledImageLabel should be physically added and revalidated into the form in the showListener

Comment: If I add the scaledImageLabel in the showListener, the gif doesnt work. The gif in the Label works fine but its height doesnt change as per the device ( ends in the middle of the screen in larger devices and tabs). I need the gif to move from top to bottom. Is there any work around?

Comment: How do you add the scaledImageLabel? Set a border around it and make sure it correctly occupies the right space when you add it in that section of the code.